# Background-color and border-image

Tags: html, css

My background-color in div with class **test** is not filling the entire container along with the border.

[image]

My code:

```
<style>
    #border {
        display:inline-block;
        border: 10px solid transparent;
        padding: 15px;
        border-image-source: url("../images/border.png");
        border-image-repeat: round;
        border-image-slice: 30;
        border-image-width: 43px;
    }
    .test{
        color:white;
        background-color:black;
    }
</style>
<div id="border"><div class="test">test</div></div>
```

How can I do to fill with the border?

Comment: give use the url of the border

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?
Use [this](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to create the `clip-path` that fits your image "border", because your border is just image pixels, isn't actually `border` I think, we have to do the trick.

```html
<style>
    #border {
        display:inline-block;
        border-image-source: url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x50");
        border-image-repeat: round;
        border-image-slice: 30;
        border-image-width: 43px;
        clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 80% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 80% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 80%, 0% 20%);
        overflow: hidden; /* added this */
    }
    .test{
        color:white;
        background-color:black;
        padding: 15px; /* moved to here */
    }
</style>
<div id="border"><div class="test">test</div></div>
```

Comment: This might do it, their image border is creating an octagon shaped border, the curve on border radius might bleed through.

Comment: Very nice, this looks correct, I will delete my answer.

Comment: @customuserlink Sorry, but I think we would need your actual `../images/border.png` image to make it work properly

Comment: Border image not appearing in your code. Because you removed the border: 10px solid transparent;

Comment: @customuserlink No, I need the polygon images background of you, then use the clip-path to make it work. When using `clip-path`, I don't very need the trick `border transparent` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
#border {
    display:inline-block;

    border-image-source: url("../images/border.png");
    border-image-repeat: round;
    border-image-slice: 30;
    border-image-width: 43px;
}
.test{
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
} </style> <div id="border"><div class="test">test</div></div>
```

Try adding border to your test class.